# use levene_test in map() function from purrr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rstatix

Is there a way to do a Levene Test via the `map()` function from the `purrr` package? Or is there another simple way to compute a Levene Test over various variables?

My data frame contains various factor and numeric columns, so I tried with `map_if()`, which works fine, e.g., for Shapiro tests. However, I do not know how to specify the formula. I want to test all my numeric variables against the "Treatment" factor.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("rstatix")

data <- data.frame(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                    .Label = c("S1 ", "S2 ", "S3 "), class = "factor"), 
                   plot = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
                                    .Label = c(" Tree 1 ", " Tree 2 ", " Tree 3 "), class = "factor"), 
                   Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), 
                   flux1 = c(11.52188065, 8.43156699, 4.495312274, -1.866676811, 3.861102035, -0.814742373, 6.51039536, 4.767950345, 10.36544542, 1.065963875), 
                   flux2 = c(0.142259208, 0.04060245, 0.807631744, 0.060127596, -0.157762562, 0.062464942, 0.043147603, 0.495001652, 0.34363348, 0.134183704), 
                   flux3 = c(0.147506197, 1.131009714, 0.038860728, 0.0176834, 0.053191593, 0.047591306, 0.00573377, -0.034926075, 0.123379247, 0.018882469))

map_if(data, is.numeric, levene_test(. ~ Treatment))
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Now also with an reproducible example ;)

Comment: It's easiest if you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). To provide some of your data, you can use `dput(head(data, 10))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative:
First pivot to long data,

Then `group_by` and apply the formula (here flux should be factor!)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("flux"),
    names_to = "flux",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  mutate(flux = as.factor(flux)) %>% 
  group_by(flux) %>% 
  levene_test(value ~ Treatment)
```

```
  flux    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <fct> <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 flux1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2 flux2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3 flux3     1     8     1.11  0.323
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use summarize a bit more directly. Then pivot and unnest the results.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric),
                   ~ list(levene_test(cur_data(), . ~ Treatment)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "flux", values_to = "levene_test") %>% 
  unnest(levene_test)
```

Another option is to just feed the variable names into map and create the formula.

```r
library(purrr)

names(data)[map_lgl(data, is.numeric)] %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr(~ levene_test(data, as.formula(paste(.x, "~ Treatment"))), .id = "flux")
```

Result (for both):

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  flux    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 flux1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2 flux2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3 flux3     1     8     1.11  0.323
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `map` loops over the columns and it is no longer a data.frame whereas `levene_test` expects a `data.frame/tibble`.   According to `?levene_test`

> data - a data frame for evaluating the formula or a model

therefore, instead of using `map_if` directly, `select` the columns that are numeric (`select(where(is.numeric))`), get  the column names (`names`), loop over those in `map`, `select` only the 'Treatment' and the looped column from the data, create the formula with `reformulate` and apply `levene_test`

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
   select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
   names %>%
   map_dfr(~ data %>%
             select(Treatment, all_of(.x)) %>% 
       {levene_test(reformulate("Treatment", response = names(.)[2]), data = .)
         })
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3     1     8     1.11  0.323
```

---

It may also done using `across` though - i.e. loop `across` the columns that are `numeric` in `summarise`, use the `data` as `cur_data()`, create the formula with `reformulate`, apply the `levene_test`, return the output in a `list`, `unclass` and use `bind_rows` (because `unclass` will remove the data.frame attribute from the `list`)

```
data %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
    ~  list(cur_data() %>%
     levene_test(reformulate("Treatment", response = cur_column()))))) %>% 
   unclass %>%
   unname %>%
   bind_rows
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3     1     8     1.11  0.323
```

---

If we need the 'flux' column identifier, either use the `summarise` step without wrapping the output in a `list` and then use `bind_rows` with `.id`

```
data %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
     ~  cur_data() %>%
      levene_test(reformulate("Treatment", response = cur_column())))) %>%
    unclass %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = 'flux')
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  flux    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 flux1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2 flux2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3 flux3     1     8     1.11  0.323
```

Or another option is with the OP's `map_if` itself

```
map_if(data, is.numeric, 
    ~ levene_test(. ~ Treatment, 
  data = tibble(.x, Treatment = data$Treatment) ), .else = ~ NULL) %>% 
   bind_rows(.id = 'flux')
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  flux    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 flux1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2 flux2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3 flux3     1     8     1.11  0.323
```